# How to set correct font size based on the resolution and dpi android

Tags: android, android-layout

In my Layout there are 3 buttons which are horizontally equally divided using weight.
Now I am setting the custom font Roboto on the button.

The problem is how to calculate the size on the font based on resolution and dpi, so that it looks proper on all sizes of android devices.

Answer (score 2):

Option #1: Specify the font size in `sp`, which takes density and user-requested font scaling into account.

Option #2: Specify the font size in `dp`, which takes density into account, but ignores the user's requested font scaling.

Option #3: Use [the logic from `AutoScaleTextView`](http://www.androidviews.net/2012/12/autoscale-textview/) to create an `AutoScaleButton` that changes its font size to fit the available space (even though this means that each button would have a different font size)

Option #4: Extend Option #3 by having a collection of `AutoScaleButton` instances negotiate a common font size among them, picking the smallest one that fits all three buttons, so that the font size is the same (even though the text might not fill two of the three buttons, depending on the caption length in characters, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

take dimension variable for all dpi

```
<dimen name="detail_photo_size">80sp</dimen>
```

in values-hdpi,values-ldpi,values-mdpi and then use like:

```
txtballoon_item_title
.setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.detail_photo_size));
```